# Unit test does not cover lines of after update trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

Here it is the Trigger on Event Activity

```
trigger eventHistoryChecker on Event (after update) 
{
    for (Event evt : Trigger.new)
    {
        Event oldevt = Trigger.oldMap.get(evt.id);
        String oldSub = oldevt.Subject;
        string newSub = evt.Subject;
        if(newSub.equals(oldSub)) { }
        else evt.addError('Can not change Subject Field');
    }
}
```

Here it is the Test Class for this Trigger but i am not sure its correct or not plz help me to resolve the problem

```
@isTest
public class eventHistoryChecker_TC
{
    static testmethod void TestMeth()
    {
        Event e=new Event();
        e.subject='Call';
        e.Ownerid='005900000037wZv';
        e.EndDateTime=System.Today();
        e.StartDateTime=System.Today();
        insert e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your trigger fires on `after update` but you never update the `Event` only insert it. You will need to change the `Subject` field once its inserted

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.Gotcha your comment got answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger is an `after upadate` trigger. So you have to perform an `update` DML to fire the trigger. Read some documentations to get more information about the trigger contexts.

1. [Trigger Context Variables](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)
2. [Context Variable Considerations](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm)

All you are doing fine just update the `Event` object to fire the trigger and test it.

```
@isTest
public class eventHistoryChecker_TC
{

    static testmethod void TestMeth()
    {
        Event e=new Event();
        e.subject='Call';
        e.Ownerid='005900000037wZv';
        e.EndDateTime=System.Today();
        e.StartDateTime=System.Today();
        insert e;

        e.subject='New One'; 
        update e;

        // add some assertEquals based on your requirement
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Telling you how to fix your code is missing the key takeaway. Just use a validation rule.

```
ISCHANGED(Subject)
```

Advantages:

- No need to unit test
- Cannot throw any exceptions
- Easy and quick to change error message

---

I want to point out some of the issues with your code though so you can avoid them in future projects.

What happens if an end user sets the new `Subject` to `null`?

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

What happens if the production environment does not have a `User` with the specified Id? Or if you just want to run your test successfully in a developer environment?

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

I recommend you look at using the [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) library to take care of filtering logic for you.

If you feel you must roll your own filters, you should at least split it out into `static` methods and separate the filter logic from the validation logic.

```
public static List<Event> hasSubjectChanged(List<Event> newEvents, Map<Id, Event> oldMap)
{
    List<Event> changed = new List<Event>();
    for (Event newEvent : newEvents)
    {
        if (newEvent.Subject != oldMap.get(newEvent.Id).Subject) changed.add(newEvent);
    }
    return changed;
}

public static void validateSubjectChange(List<Event> invalidEvents)
{
    for (Event invalidEvent : invalidEvents)
        invalidEvent.addError('Cannot change Subject Field');
}
```

These methods would be easy to call from your trigger:

```
validateSubjectChange(hasSubjectChanged(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap));
```

If you use Selector:

```
validateSubjectChange(
    Select.Field.hasChanged(Event.Subject).filter(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap)
);
```